# Apache ignite single cache(map) event registration for cache event

Tags: java, events, caching, ignite

I am looking for a way to register single cache's cache event with ignite.

It is possible to register all put events of ignite envoriment with this code;

```
        IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, CacheEvent> lsnr = new IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, CacheEvent>() {
                @Override public boolean apply(UUID uuid, CacheEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Received event [evt=" + evt.name() + ", key=" + evt.key() +
                        ", oldVal=" + evt.oldValue() + ", newVal=" + evt.newValue());

                    return true; // Continue listening.
                }
            };
    ignite.events().localListen(lsnr, EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT);
```

But i would like to register only cache event for specific map(cache) because of performance reasons. Otherwise, i will have to check cache name for each event, which could cause huge load on system with a high number of transactions.

Thanks for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to data updates, continuous queries are better option: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries

This feature works on per-cache level, supports proper event ordering and guarantees delivery in case of topology changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What if i say, i want to listen only local updates, is it possible with continous query.

Comment: And also will it be possible to catch remove event with continous query approach. Thanks

Comment: To listen only to local events, use `ContinuousQuery.setLocal(true)` flag.

Comment: Any data change (insert, update, remove) is reflected in the listener. See `CacheEntryEvent.getEventType()`.